# scatter plot with hourly time in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time, scatter-plot

i want to plot a scatter plot between mentioned two columns `p` and `s`. `p` should be on x axis showing time on hourly basis for 24 hours and `s` should be on y axis. I have already tried but not getting the expected output.
I tried the following code:

[image]

I am not recieving output as expected  because y axis value should range from `0` to `300` (column `s` from data) and x axis should range from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`.
The xpected output is a scatter plot with column `s` on y axis and just the time of column `p` (only time no date in the format `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`)  on x axis.
Snapshot of the data:

[image]

Comment: Why are you plotting `time` column and not `k` on the x axis in your code?

Comment: @Jonas since in my code , column is renamed as "time" but actually its k. and i just want to use the time part of k column not the date and plot the scatter plot

Comment: That might be the issue, that you convert the `k` column to date only (i.e. get rid of the hour). Plotting `k` on the x axis works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably converted the datetime to day only (i.e. got rid of the hours). Using the `k` column to plot directly works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"k": [datetime(2020, 5, 26, 6, 12), datetime(2020, 5, 26, 6, 13), datetime(2020, 5, 26, 6, 13)], 
                  "s": [88, 105, 290]})

plt.scatter(df["k"].dt.strftime("%H:%M"), df["s"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: df is just having 3 values how can i fetch entire data and i just want hours on x axis but i am getting dates.

Comment: just replace `df` with the name of your dataframe... Are the columns all the same date? If not, you can get rid of the date entirely by doing `plt.scatter(df["k"].dt.strftime("%H:%M"), df["s"])`.